# Xamarin Forms - Popup Menu or Equivalent

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, popupmenu, searchbar

I'm looking for a way to display a popup menu under a Search Bar in Xamarin Forms (like in the Google Play app for example but not the same design).

It may be possible to achieve this feature with an Absolute Layout but this is not very recommended and not very precise depending on the screen size of the device.

I would be very grateful if we could find a solution.

Thanks.

**Google Play App Example**

[image: Google Play App Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the Xamarin Forms AutoCompleteView from the labs

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/AutoCompleteView